# Mac office.js Word add-in open pdf using window.open

Tags: office-addins, office-js

Env: Mac, Office 2016 build 15.26

On a button click, I fetch pdf base64 bytes from the server and call window.open to launch another browser instance to open pdf.

window.open("data:application/pdf;base64,"+ pdfbytes)

On Windows add-in, it works fine.
On Mac, the dialog box appears asking "choose application to launch'data:application/pdf"
All the applications are grayed out, so I could not select Safari or Chrome to launch pdf.

When I open add-in URL from Chrome browser on Mac, and click the same button, it launched new Chrome tab instance and opens the pdf fine.

Any better way to show pdf through word add-in?

Comment: Hello thanks for the question. we are investigating and will come with an answer shortly. stay tuned....

Comment: HI @JuanBalmori, any update on this?

Comment: was a bug, but its fixed and will be available soon, please check the december update for Word and let me know how it goes... thanks!

Answer (score 0):

this is a bug in the product, its now fixed and will ship as part of the December Office update  for Mac. thanks for reporting this and making our platform better!